# dojo grid dynamic options for a cell

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, dojo

I am trying to display dropdown for a cell in data grid on double click of the cell.

The data I want to display in the cell of datagrid on double click is stored in a dojo store.

I am using the following code but is not working. Please help me in understanding what am I doing wrong.
(clinStore has the clinician id's which I need to display in the 'clinicianId' field of the grid on double clicking the cell.)

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
var clinStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ data : ${clinidresult} } );

gridLayout = [{ defaultCell: { width: 8, editable: true, type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget, styles: 'text-align: right;'  },
    rows: [
        { name: 'corporateEntityCode', field: 'corporateEntityCode', editable: false },
        { name: 'clinicianId', field: 'clinicianId', editable: true, styles: 'text-align: center;', type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget, widgetClass: dijit.form.FilteringSelect, 
            widgetProps: {store: clinStore}},
    ]
}];
```

I am displaying my data grid as follows:

```
<div id="grid" data-dojo-id="grid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="memberClinicianStore" rowSelector="20px" structure="gridLayout" escapeHTMLInData="false"style="width: 100%; height: 200px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few ideas for starters..

You are missing a space in here before style: escapeHTMLInData="false"style="width: 100%; height: 200px" ...

Try setting an px width for your grid, tool not percentage.

It would help to know which version of Dojo you are working with and it would be great if you can list your dojo.require statements at the top of your javascript code to show that you have them all and they are listed correctly. Appropriate .css code is also useful to help debug as incorrect css can mess up a grid, too. Last, if you are adapting the code from a web page, that is also good info to have to make it easier to debug!